# Excel VBA Get Frame and Image Name on Double Click

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a solution for getting information on my Userform when I double click an image frame. I have a Userform with 7 frames and within each frame I have 4 image frames. What I would like to do is double click an image and get information from it without having to write special code for each frame. Basically just double click the image and get the Frame Name and/or Caption Text AND the Image Name Text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This gets me the Frame Text... now how to get this PLUS the Image Name and/or Caption inside of this Frame?

```
Private Sub Image_Yellow_Click()
MsgBox Me.ActiveControl.Caption
End Sub
```

Comment: any code so far you can post?

Comment: I don't have code yet for what I am trying to do, I just need to know how to do it.

Comment: Anyone? Is this impossible? I cannot get past the Frame text no matter what I try. Please help!

Answer (score -1):

Private Sub Image1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

```
UserForm1.Hide

    MsgBox "Hello World!", 65536

UserForm1.Show
```

End Sub

Comment: edit your answer to show the code in the right format.